# How do I periodically call a function in the non-interrupt context?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

In the Linux kernel, I need to periodically check the state of the switch chip by calling the `mdiobus_read()` (drivers/net/phy/mdio_bus.c).

I tried to use Linux timer `add_timer()` but I found out that the callback is called in the interrupt context. Actually, there is a warning in the comment to the function `mdiobus_read()`:

> NOTE: MUST NOT be called from interrupt context,
>   because the bus read/write functions may wait for an interrupt
>   to conclude the operation.

So, how to periodically call the function `mdiobus_read()`?

Comment: You do not want to run in interrupt context. So, which context do you want your code to run in? The only other context is process-context, so you need a process for that. Thus, you'll need a kernel thread to do the work.

Comment: @UliSchlachter, thank you. That's what I need